# python: Convert vector of symbolic eigenfunctions to matrix of evaluated functions

Tags: python

I'm writing a script for my PDE homework in python and I'm using `SymPy`. I have my solution as a vector of symbolic eigenfunctions e.g.

```
u(x,y)=sum(c_n*X(x)_n*Y(y)_n)
```

and now I need to evaluate each eigenfunction

```
u(x,y) on x=[0,L] and y=[0,M]
```

Any hints?

Comment: What `u(x,y)=sum(c_nX(x)_nY(y)_n)` does mean, can you make your function a bit more clear?

Comment: I have a vector of constants c_n, and two vectors of symbolic equations (X(x)_n and Y(y)_n), the elements of which depend on incremented eigenvalues. So, my final solution needs to be the sum of the products of each vector. So, I need to sum c[n=1]*X[n=1](x=0,L)*Y(n=1(y=0,M)+c[n=2]*X[n=2](x=0,L)*Y[n=2](y=0,M)+...c[n=N]*X[n=N](x=0,L)*Y[n=N](y=0,M). I think I've figured out how to do it with nested for loops, but I figure there's probably an easier way.